# Does Notepad (Version 6.1) under Windows7 ignore the end line code?

Tags: matlab, windows-7, notepad

I use notepad versio 6.1 (build:7501: ServicePack1) under Windows 7 to creating some .txt file for Matlab Meteolab toolbox. But when I read these txt file I got the following error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in parseDomain (line 36)
        varTable.Maximum=varTable.Maximum(I2);

Error in getFRCfromNetCDF (line 129)
dmn=parseDomain(dmn,tableFileName);

Error in loadGCM (line 162)
        [data,dmn]=getFRCfromNetCDF(ctl,dmn,'dates',anDate,'anhour',anHour,'interpolator',interpolator,'warning',warnings,'landmask',landMask,'threshold',threshold,'path',rootPath,'boundingbox',bound
```

These error messages stem from the fact that there are not endline codes in my .txt files. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Notepad doesn't really qualify as a text editor, it is a thin wrapper around a text box control. Use a decent text editor that allows you to specify line endings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Finaly I could solve this matter using Paul's suggestion what is similar that you wrote (http://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks). I copied the text from notepad and pasted to word and I copied the text from word back to txt. It solved the matter.

Comment: @Beata ... throw away `notepad` and consider alternatives. A nice one to start would be [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), but they are many many other which are all better than `notepad`.